# Reorganizing Android storage

Tags: storage

My Android device (rk2928, Android 4.1.1) currently has NAND flash on `sdcard` and the SD card on `external_sd`. Moving an app to SD keeps it in flash but takes up more of it total, so I'd like to reallocate the NAND flash used for `sdcard` into internal memory and then have the SD card on `sdcard`. How can I do this? Or is there a *very good* reason why I should not do this?

Results of `df`:

```
Filesystem             Size   Used   Free   Blksize
/dev                  197.2M  36.0K  197.2M   4096
/mnt/asec             197.2M  0.0 K  197.2M   4096
/mnt/obb              197.2M  0.0 K  197.2M   4096
/system               511.6M  393.0M  118.6M   1024
/data                 1007.9M  840.3M  167.6M   4096
/cache                124.0M  16.1M  107.9M   4096
/mnt/external_sd      14.9G  10.2G  4.7 G   8192
/mnt/sdcard           1.7 G  1.0 G  658.5M   8192
/mnt/secure/asec      1.7 G  1.0 G  658.5M   8192
/mnt/asec/<apps follow> ...
```

Results of `mount`:

```
rootfs / rootfs ro,relatime 0 0
tmpfs /dev tmpfs rw,nosuid,relatime,mode=755 0 0
devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,relatime,mode=600 0 0
proc /proc proc rw,relatime 0 0
sysfs /sys sysfs rw,relatime 0 0
none /acct cgroup rw,relatime,cpuacct 0 0
tmpfs /mnt/asec tmpfs rw,relatime,mode=755,gid=1000 0 0
tmpfs /mnt/obb tmpfs rw,relatime,mode=755,gid=1000 0 0
none /dev/cpuctl cgroup rw,relatime,cpu 0 0
/dev/block/mtdblock8 /system ext4 ro,noatime,nodiratime,barrier=1,data=ordered,noauto_da_alloc 0 0
/dev/block/mtdblock6 /data ext4 rw,nosuid,nodev,noatime,nodiratime,barrier=1,data=ordered,noauto_da_alloc 0 0
/dev/block/mtdblock5 /cache ext4 rw,nosuid,nodev,noatime,nodiratime,barrier=1,data=ordered,noauto_da_alloc 0 0
/sys/kernel/debug /sys/kernel/debug debugfs rw,relatime 0 0
/dev/block/vold/179:0 /mnt/external_sd vfat rw,dirsync,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,nodiratime,uid=1000,gid=1015,fmask=0002,dmask=0002,allow_utime=0020,codepage=cp437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro 0 0
/dev/block/vold/31:9 /mnt/sdcard vfat rw,dirsync,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,nodiratime,uid=1000,gid=1015,fmask=0002,dmask=0002,allow_utime=0020,codepage=cp437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro 0 0
/dev/block/vold/31:9 /mnt/secure/asec vfat rw,dirsync,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,nodiratime,uid=1000,gid=1015,fmask=0002,dmask=0002,allow_utime=0020,codepage=cp437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro 0 0
tmpfs /mnt/sdcard/.android_secure tmpfs ro,relatime,size=0k,mode=000 0 0
/dev/block/dm-0 /mnt/asec/<apps follow> ...
```

Comment: What's your device? Are you rooted? You might find what you're looking for on [XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com).

Comment: It is a rooted EM743. XDA has lots of information on other devices, but I couldn't find anything concrete on my specific device. I was hoping that generic information about modifying mtd partitions was available somewhere rather than me having to dig through half a dozen to several dozen documents to find what I wanted.